# Wrong colors in JList when using Nimbus and Java 8U20

Tags: java, swing, java-8, look-and-feel, nimbus

My application uses wrong colors for JList since I updated to the latest Java 8 version (U20). E.g. instead of dark blue for selected items a light gray is actually used.

Simple test application:

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel;



public class Test {

    public Test() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());

            JList<String> l = new JList<>();
            DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
            model.add(0, "sssssssss");
            model.add(1, "sssssssss");
            model.add(2, "sssssssss");
            model.add(3, "sssssssss");
            l.setModel(model);

            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setSize(500, 500);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.add(l);
            f.pack();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Test();
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Java 7, Java 8

[image: Java 7, Java 8 <U20]

Java 8 U20:

[image: Java 8 U20]

`JList.getSelectionBackground()` returns

```
DerivedColor(color=57,105,138 parent=nimbusSelectionBackground offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=57,105,138
```

but actually it is not RGB(57,105,138) but the above mentioned light gray.

Comment: Shows your intended color with `1.8.0_05`. The change must have been introduced between that version and `1.8.0_20`.

Comment: The only change I can spot between these version is that the `Color` is u `UIResource` now, i.e. the class is `DerivedColor$UIResource` instead of `DerivedColor`.

Comment: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8041725

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8057791

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restore the exact behavior of versions before `1.8.0_20` with the following initialization code:

```
final NimbusLookAndFeel laf = new NimbusLookAndFeel();
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
UIDefaults defaults = laf.getDefaults();
defaults.put("List[Selected].textForeground",
    laf.getDerivedColor("nimbusLightBackground", 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0, false));
defaults.put("List[Selected].textBackground",
    laf.getDerivedColor("nimbusSelectionBackground", 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0, false));
defaults.put("List[Disabled+Selected].textBackground",
    laf.getDerivedColor("nimbusSelectionBackground", 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0, false));
defaults.put("List[Disabled].textForeground",
    laf.getDerivedColor("nimbusDisabledText", 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0, false));
defaults.put("List:\"List.cellRenderer\"[Disabled].background",
    laf.getDerivedColor("nimbusSelectionBackground", 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0, false));
```

This reverts what have changed between `1.8.0_05` and `1.8.0_20` in the class `NimbusDefaults`. The parameter `false` has been removed (which turns it effectively to `true` via the overloaded method). This change turns the `Color`s into `UIResource`s what may be formally correct, but for whatever reason it causes the problem you have encountered. So re-inserting the `false` restores the old behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
Here is how I solved it for my application:

```
 ...

 for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
  ...

  UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("List[Selected].textBackground", new Color(57, 105, 138));
  UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("List[Selected].textForeground", Color.WHITE);
```

Here is a list of the UIManager's (Color) Keys:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html

Hope this helps you,

**Edit:** Tested with your provided code. It works.

Best regards